# Google maps v2 not displayed on new activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I have issues as I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQ__ECAEAS0 , how to implement Google maps v2 in android project, I did exactly like in tutorial just in new activity and then i try to open new activity , The application is crashing each time: Sorry new to android...

**Creating new activity:**

```
public void openMap(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapMain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**XML:**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bMapas"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonSettings"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textpowererdBy"
        android:background="@drawable/st_nohow_b"
        android:onClick="openMap"
        android:text="@string/map" />
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nl.test.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 <permission android:name="nl.test.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="nl.test.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapMain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_main" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="AIzaSyAnNGd2_lI-3-wS0XR06czsjDQNTAATQXF" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat**

```
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.test.app/nl.test.app.MapMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at nl.test.app.MapMain.onCreate(MapMain.java:16)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  ... 11 more
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:660)
08-12 13:31:25.536: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: Follow this- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: post the LogCat with your errors!

Comment: Whats the Error you got in Log-cat.post the log-cat error

Comment: @Yugesh Updated added LogCat logs

Comment: @VadimasSizikovas see the Emil Adz answer below.you miss that meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice imidatly is that you don't have this part in you Manifest file:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

`Google Maps API V2` will not run without this `meta-data` section in your Manifest file.

If this is not working still after making this change, try to go over this blog post I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

You can as well go over this tutorial to make sure you are getting the key and setting up the API Console the right way:

[Google Maps API V2 Key Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)